# can not swap array elements c++

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

I am new to C++. I am trying to solve a problem in the textbook: swap the first and last element in an array. But when I run the code I wrote, nothing happened and even the sentence "Please enter the numbers in the array: " does not show up. Anyone could give some help? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int swap(int values[], int size)
{
    int temp = values[0];
    values[0] = values[size-1];
    values[size-1] = temp;
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int test[SIZE];
    cout << "Please enter the numbers in the array: " << endl;
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
            test[i] = input;
    }
    swap(test, SIZE);
    cout << test[SIZE] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are some output on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/s4BjWjV9SVjoKkAl). Anyway, `cout << test[SIZE] << endl;` acccess out of bounds and it is bad.

Comment: `swap()` has a return type other than void but does not return anything.

Comment: Moreover, you fill the array with the same single input value in all cells. Swaping the cells yield no visible result.

Comment: Are you aware that the name `swap` already exists in namespace `std`, which you're bringing into the global scope with your `using namespace std;`? It won't cause problems here because overload resolution picks your function, but you'll run into clashes in future if you insist on `using namespace std`.

Comment: It is an anti-pattern and a bad habit to use constants in UPPERCASE (unless it is a preprocessor macro), please avoid that.

Comment: `even the sentence "Please enter the numbers in the array: " does not show up.` are you compiling *and* running or just compiling?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Here return type should be void as you are not returning value.
void swap(int values[], int size)
{
   int temp = values[0];
   values[0] = values[size-1];
   values[size-1] = temp;
}

int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 5;
   int test[SIZE];
   cout << "Please enter the numbers in the array: " << endl;

   //USE LOOP TO TAKE INPUT ONE BY ONE IN AN ARRAY
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cin >> test[i];

   swap(test, SIZE);

   //USE LOOP TO DISPLAY ELEMENT ONE BY ONE
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     cout << test[i] << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `size` instead of `SIZE`? ALL-CAPS identifiers are best reserved for macros.

Comment: And in C++11: `for(auto& e : test) std::cin >> e; swap(test, SIZE); for(auto e : test) std::cout << e << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

There were a few mistakes:

- You should get the input inside the loop and then assign it to the test array.
- When printing the swapped value, access the test array with `SIZE-1` instead of `SIZE`, because array indexes run from `0` to `SIZE-1`, inclusive.
- You declared `swap()` as returning `int`, but provided no `return` statement (this suggests that you haven't enabled enough warnings from your compiler).

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  void swap(int values[], int size)
  {
      int temp = values[0];
      values[0] = values[size-1];
      values[size-1] = temp;
  }

  int main()
  {
      const int SIZE = 5;
      int test[SIZE];
      int input;
      cout << "Please enter the numbers in the array: " << endl;

      for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
      {
              cin >> input;
              test[i] = input;
      }
      swap(test, SIZE);
      cout << test[SIZE-1] << endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```